# Remove last "X" characters from string

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

I have a string that can end will several "X" characters.
Let's say the string ends in commas like this.

```
string X = "1,2,3,,,";
```

I need some function or lambda expression that can remove the last set of commas.
I will have no way of knowing how many commas there are at the end of the string but the end result should look like this.

```
?x -- "1,2,3";
```

Comment: Did you even search for an answer before posting this?

Comment: @roryap Obviously I didn't do a good job at reading the posts. I thought TrimEnd would remove the last "X" character not the last "X" character(S). Sorry that I miss understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need regex or LINQ, use [`String.TrimEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
X = X.TrimEnd(',');
```

You can use it with multiple characters, f.e. if you want to remove trailing commas and dots:

```
X = X.TrimEnd(',', '.');
```

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid. That was simple. Thanks.

Comment: It will work only if the character is known. Perhaps, that is all what is necessary in this case.

Comment: @stribizhev: how could you remove something that you don't know? You can always use variables or collections in `TrimEnd` which are initialized at runtime.

Comment: Easily. For example, remove only the final digits. Or final closing punctuation. Or both categories. Then, you'll need a regex.

Comment: @stribizhev: of course `TrimEnd` is not a replacement for regex, it still has it's place ;)